# (Python + PyQt5) Como não deixar aplicação principal ser fechada sem fechar janelas "filhas" abertas.?

Tags: python

Eu tenho minha aplicação principal com menus (MenuBar) onde chama a função que cria e abre outra janela "filha".

Meu problema está na parte em que eu consigo fechar minha aplicação principal sem antes ter fechado essa janela filha.

Como bloquear fechamento do sistema sem antes ter fechado todas as janelas filhas abertas?

Código da aplicação principal.

```
class ViewMainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, controller_main):
        super(ViewMainWindow, self).__init__()
        self.ui_main_window = Ui_main_MainWindow()
        self.ui_main_window.setupUi(self)

        self._controller_main = controller_main
        self._view_scd_window = ViewSCDWindow()

        self.ui_main_window.action_SCD.triggered.connect(self._view_scd_window.create_scd_window)
```

Código da janela filha:

```
class ViewSCDWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(ViewSCDWindow, self).__init__()
        self.ui_scd_window = Ui_scd_form()
        self.ui_scd_window.setupUi(self)

    def create_scd_window(self):
        self.show()
```

Todas as janelas são herdadas do modelo criado pelo QT Design.

Comment: isso aqui é exatamente o que você precisa https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18256459/qdialog-prevent-closing-in-python-and-pyqt. Não tenho pericia suficiente no pyqt para arriscar uma resposta.

Comment: Obrigado pela tentativa de ajuda @Filipe Gonçalves mas infelizmente não é exatamente isso que estou precisando. Basicamente preciso que ao capturar o evento "accept" do closeEvent() seja feito uma varredura para saber se tem alguma janela ativa e caso tenha, não deixe fechar o sistema sem fechar as janelas, ou feche todas juntas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui resolve o problema seguindo a ideia no caminho:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36768033/pyqt-how-to-open-new-window.

Desse modo adaptei minha aplicação e ficou exatamente como quero, ou seja, só fecha o sistema se não tiver nenhuma janela aberta, ou fecha todas as janelas abertas.